# Adding images as part of a one to many relationship

Tags: java, html, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been stuck on an issue with a one to many relationship database. I am trying to upload images to a record in the database, but everything I try is not working. Basically, I want to allow a user to upload different pictures of the pet into a database. There is one resident, but multiple pets, each pet can have multiple images, some images may be null. I am trying to store the image as a byte[], but if there is a better way of doing it please let me know. I am asking for a fresh pair of eyes to see what I am not seeing.

Resident Model

```
public class Residents
    {
        [Key]
        public int ResidentId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string UnitNo { get; set; } = string.Empty;   
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Surname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string ResTel1 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string ResTel2 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public DateTime ApplicationDate { get; set; }
        //[Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string PetAmount { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string ApplicationSigned { get; set; } = "No";
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string TrusteeAppStatus { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public virtual List<Pets> Pets { get; set; } = new List<Pets>();
    }
}
```

Pets Model

```
public class Pets
    {
        [Key]
        public int PetId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ResID")]
        public int ResID { get; set; }
        public virtual Residents Resident { get; private set; }
        public string PetName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string PetType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string PetSex { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string PetDesc { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string PetChip { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string PetChipImageUrl { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Display(Name = "Pet Chip Image")]
        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile? PetChipImage { get; set; }
        public string PetSterile { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string PetSterileImageUrl { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Display(Name = "Pet Sterile Image")]
        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile? PetSterileImage { get; set; }
        public string PetStatus { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string PetAdditional { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string PetImageUrl { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Display(Name = "Pet Sterile Image")]
        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile? PetImage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        { 
            Residents residents = new Residents();
            residents.Pets.Add(new Pets() { PetId = 1 });
            return View(residents);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Residents residents)
        {
            foreach (Pets pets in residents.Pets)
            {
                if (pets.PetName == null || pets.PetName.Length == 0)
                    residents.Pets.Remove(pets);
            }

           
            _context.Residents.Add(residents);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
```

CSHTML

```
<div id="PetInput" class="col-md-12">
                    <table id="PetAdd" class="table table-striped table-sm">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Pet name
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Type
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Gender
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Description
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Chipped?
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Sterilized?
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Status
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Additional Info
                                </th>
                                <th>

                                </th>
                                </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @*@foreach (var item in Model.Pets)*@
                            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Pets.Count; i++)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Pets[i].PetName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
                                        @*<input asp-for="@item.PetName" class="form-control" />*@
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Pets[i].PetType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
                                        @*<input asp-for="@item.PetType" class="form-control" />*@
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @*@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Pets[i].PetSex, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })*@
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Pets[i].PetSex, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(PetGender))),"Select")
                                        @*<input asp-for="@item.PetSex" class="form-control" />*@
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Pets[i].PetDesc, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
                                        @*<input asp-for="@item.PetDesc" class="form-control" />*@
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @*@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Pets[i].PetChip, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })*@
                                         @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Pets[i].PetChip, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(ChooseYesNo))),"Select")
                                        @*<input asp-for="@item.PetChip" class="form-control" />*@
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @*@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Pets[i].PetSterile, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })*@
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Pets[i].PetSterile, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(ChooseYesNo))),"Select")
                                        @*<input asp-for="@item.PetSterile" class="form-control" />*@
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Pets[i].PetStatus, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
                                        @*<input asp-for="@item.PetStatus" class="form-control" />*@
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Pets[i].PetAdditional, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
                                        @*<input asp-for="@item.PetAdditional" class="form-control" />*@
                                    </td>
                                    
                                </tr>
                                
                                
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        Add an image of the microchip certificate<br />
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Pets[i].PetChipImage, new { type = "file" })
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Pets[i].PetChipImageUrl, new { type = "file", @onchange ="encodeImageFileAsURL(this)"})
                                       
                                    </td>
                                    <td colspan="4">
                                        Add an image of the sterilization certificate<br />
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Pets[i].PetSterileImage, new { type = "file" })
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Pets[i].PetSterileImageUrl, new { type = "file" })
                                    </td>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        Add an image your pet<br />
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Pets[i].PetImage, new { type = "file" })
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Pets[i].PetImageUrl, new { type = "file" })
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                    <button id='btnadd-@i' type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary visible"
                                                onclick="AddItem(this)" >Add</button>
                                    <button id='btnremove-@i' type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary invisible"
                                                onclick="DeleteItem(this)">Delete</button>
                                    </td> 
                               </tr>
```

Java Script

```
function encodeImageFileAsURL(element) {
    var file = element.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        console.log('RESULT', reader.result)
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Comment: By not going into depth of the question, usually in these cases, I upload files on a server and store the URL in the database, then those links can be directly opened on UI. Saves a lot of headaches

Comment: So what's the problem you have met?

Comment: The images don't get stored in the database table "Pets" once a Resident record is added. The other details save - just not the images.

Comment: You can refer to this [doc](https://tutexchange.com/how-to-upload-files-and-save-in-database-in-asp-net-core-mvc/) about how to upload file and save in database.